# Slow to open files from Server 2008r2 with exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-office-2007

I have a domain with windows 7 pro x86 and x64 bit computers on it.  Users are experiencing slow load times for office documents that are shared on a network share off the same server that houses the exchange2010.  The symptoms are that a downloading bar at the bottom of the document appears when they open it and then the file takes between 30secs-5mins to open.  I beleive it is happening as a result of an exchange error occuring on the server but dont know how to confirm/disconfirm this suspicion

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're just talking about files being shared out of an NTFS folder on the server computer's hard disk drive (and not something like files being shared out of an Exchange public folder) I doubt that Exchange is related, per se.

Exchange could be bottlenecking your I/O. You should look at the I/O load on the server computer using Performance Monitor and make sure that you're not building up a high disk queue on the spindle where the shared files are located.

I'd sniff the traffic between the client and the server when opening the file to see what the character of the network bandwidth utilization is. You may find that the file transfers quickly and the client spends time, following the transfer, doing *something*.

I suspect, based on your tag "office-2007", that you're talking about problems opening Microsoft Office files. I've had Office-aware anti-virus software negatively effect file load times and, had I not sniffed the traffic, I wouldn't have seen that the file transfer was long-since done before the client appeared to finally "open" the document.

Benchmark transferring a large file by copying it with Windows Explorer. If the file transfers quickly that way then you're probably better off delving into the Office programs' operation with something like SysInternals Process Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Evan a bit, but loading file-level AV on the same server as you're running Exchange has been known to have some strange side-effects. Especially if the Exchange AV is made by the same company as the file-level AV. The two packages I've used, Symantec Endpoint Protection and Microsoft ForeFront, were rather clear that you should not run file-level AV on the Exchange server at all. I suspect you're finding out why that's the case.

A way to test this is to see how long it takes to copy off non-Office files from those shares. If those go fast, but office does not, then the chances of a horrible AV interaction increase.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Evan and sysadmin. Eset Nod32 4.2 file system protection caused exactly this problem. Disabling file system protection on the server with Exchange 2010 and file services did the trick